Smoothness of $\int_{a}^{b}f(x,t)dt$ with respect to $x$
Consider the map $f:[0,1]\times [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$. I suppose that $f$ is smooth on the open set $(0,1)\times (a,b)$. My goal is to show (if it is true) that the map $x\mapsto \int_{a}^{b}f(x,t)dx$ is smooth in $x$ on $(0,1)$.
My attempt is that, since $a$ and $b$ are finite, then by Leibniz rule, all the maps $x\mapsto \int_{a}^{b}f_x(x,t)dt$ exist, which should therefore imply that they are continuous since differentiability implies continuity.
Similarly, if $f$ is smooth on $[0,1]\times (a,b)$, then we conclude on smoothness of $x\mapsto \int_{a}^{b}f(x,t)dt$ on $[0,1]$.
This seems however too simple to be correct ... I'm trying to understand if I made a mistake in my reasoning.

Smoothness on the open set (even for finite $a,b$) doesn’t imply the integral is well defined. You need to make some changes to the statement, then it becomes true.

Thank you! I got it now. I need the integrability of $f_x$. In the case where $f$ is smooth on $[a,b]$ and not just $(a,b)$, this integrability follows from the integrability of continuous functions on compact sets.
